# Java OpenGL Perspective matrix not working

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, lwjgl

I'm trying to render a simple triangle with OpenGL in Java using LWJGL3. 
Everything is working great, but the projection matrix (perspective) is not working. In C++ I just used to apply the `glm::perspective()` method which works just great. But in Java, I implemented it myself since there are no libraries like GLM handling it.
So here the code for the perspective in Java :

```
public mat4 perspective(float fov, float aspect, float zNear, float zFar){
        mat4 projection = new mat4();

        float halfTanFov = (float) Math.tan(Math.toRadians(fov / 2));
        float frustum = zNear - zFar; 

        projection.m[0][0] = 1f / halfTanFov * aspect; 
        projection.m[1][1] = 1f / halfTanFov; 
        projection.m[2][2] = - ((zNear + zFar) / frustum); 
        projection.m[2][3] = 2 * zFar * zNear / frustum; 
        projection.m[3][2] = 1; 

        return projection; 
    }
```

I created the `mat4` class and this is how I apply a multiplication :

```
for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
            for(int j=0; j<4; j++){
                result.m[i][j] = matrix.m[i][0] * m[0][j] + 
                                 matrix.m[i][1] * m[1][j] +
                                 matrix.m[i][2] * m[2][j] +
                                 matrix.m[i][3] * m[3][j];
            }
```

Of course I tested this multiplication and a compared a result with my TI output, and it worked great. 
Other information, the default `constructor` for the `mat4` class is putting all the values to 0. 
here is the code :

```
public void setZero(){
        m[0][0] = 0; m[0][1] = 0; m[0][2] = 0; m[0][3] = 0; 
        m[1][0] = 0; m[1][1] = 0; m[1][2] = 0; m[1][3] = 0; 
        m[2][0] = 0; m[2][1] = 0; m[2][2] = 0; m[2][3] = 0; 
        m[3][0] = 0; m[3][1] = 0; m[3][2] = 0; m[3][3] = 0; 
    }
```

the `viewMatrix()` in the other hand is working great. It's a simple implementation of the `lookAt()` method. 
So when it's `lookAtMatrix * modelMatrix * position` where the `vec4 position` the result is good. 
But when I try to add the projection matrix for the MVP : `perspective * lookatMatrix * model * position` the result is nothing. 
Here where I do it in the code :

```
public mat4 getViewProjection() {
    mViewProjection = Transform.getInstance().lookAt(mPosition, mPosition.add(mDirection), mUp);
    return mViewProjection;
}
public mat4 getMVP(mat4 model){
    return mPerspective.mult(getViewProjection()).mult(model);
}
```

And here is my simple GLSL shader (for the vertex shader ) :

```
#version 430

layout(location=0) in vec3 position; 
uniform mat4 MVP;

void main(void){
    gl_Position = MVP * vec4(position, 1); 
}
```

I tried other implementation of the perspective without success, so I guess my mistake is somewhere else, but sadly enough, I can't figure out where. If someone could help, it'd be great ! thank you. 
If you other informations, please ask me and I'll post it.

Answer (score 0):

There might be other ways of defining a projection matrix. But at least compared to the projection matrices I've normally used with OpenGL, you have a couple of signs inverted. In this:

```
projection.m[0][0] = 1f / halfTanFov * aspect; 
projection.m[1][1] = 1f / halfTanFov; 
projection.m[2][2] = - ((zNear + zFar) / frustum); 
projection.m[2][3] = 2 * zFar * zNear / frustum; 
projection.m[3][2] = 1;
```

The signs might actually be ok if you want your camera to look in direction of the **positive** z-axis in eye coordinate space. It's much more common to have the camera look down the **negative** z-axis.

More importantly, it looks like your matrix is transposed. At least as long as you specify matrices in column major order, which is the way it's normally done with OpenGL, and which seems consistent with the code you posted.

With these two corrections, the code should be:

```
projection.m[0][0] = 1f / halfTanFov * aspect; 
projection.m[1][1] = 1f / halfTanFov; 
projection.m[2][2] = (zNear + zFar) / frustum; 
projection.m[3][2] = 2 * zFar * zNear / frustum; 
projection.m[2][3] = -1f;
```